# Debian install has written the grub loader into my primary disk master boot

Tags: debian, boot, grub, macintosh

I have attempted to install Debian to my external USB HDD (for which I had previously created a 150GB ext4 partition on it).

I have done these operations from my Macbook pro (on which I had installed rEFind)

Here are what I did:

1) Flashed Debian DVD install on a USB thumb

2) Booted on it

3) Proceed to install Debian

3a) I have selected "manual" at the disk step
   3b) I have selected my 150GB ext4 partition to be mounted as '/'
   3c) I did not chose any swap

4) The Debian install process finished and **I was a bit worried because it did not ask me where to install GRUB** ... (I want to install it on my external HDD master boot)

When I restarted the macbook instead of going to the usual rEFind screen it went straight to a grub error screen where it says device xxxxxxxx could not be found

I restarted again the Macbook by holding "alt" and thankfully the Mac boot manager appeared and I could boot into my OSX.

From there I have re installed rEFind, restarted and the rEFind screen appeared again (uufff!) **and I could see both the OSX and Debian choice.**
(which by the way if I chose it with my HDD plugged in, boot perfectly fine into Debian)

Can I erase the debian entry on my primary drive master boot and put it on the external HDD instead?